# Postgres Как найти ближайшие числа?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица - соотношение.

```
0.5 - 3
1.0 - 5.4
```

Зависимость эмпирическая (т.е. вычислена в реальных условиях). Формулой не описывается.
Шаг таблицы - 0.5

Как в зависимости от того что ввел пользователь вытащить соответствующее число?

[image: y5bAxLg.png]

По умному нужно рассчитывать по формуле

```
y = ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (y2 - y1) + y1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *  from (
select t.*, abs(value - 1.1) as diff
from   t
order by diff asc  
limit 2
) x
order by value
```

найдет два ближайших числа